# Convert "Patient Expired on Mar-07-2018 6:33 AM" to 2018-03-07

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to convert "Patient Expired on Mar-07-2018 6:33 AM" to 2018-03-07 in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

One pretty simple method:

```
select convert(date, replace(substring(str, 20, 11), '-', ' ')
from (values ('Patient Expired on Mar-07-2018 6:33 AM')) v(str)
```

Comment: I have to covert the whole column to Date? How can I do that?

Comment: I have to covert the whole column which looks like                    
Patient Expired on Mar-29-2018.
Patient Expired on Mar-29-2018.
Patient Expired on Apr-12-2018.
Patient Expired on Mar-07-2018 9:20 PM.
Patient Expired on Mar-10-2018 7:40 PM.
Patient Expired on Mar-05-2018 11:20 PM.
Patient Expired on Mar-29-2018.
Patient Expired on Mar-01-2018 2:33 AM.                                      convert the whole column to Date. How can I do that?

Comment: @Karthik . . . What don't you get?  You just put your table name in the `from` clause and put the correct column name in the `select` expression.